# Sending post request through Postman works but not when using http

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework, postman

I am working on uploading an image to my server (right now it is just localhost). Below is the part of the code in my `views.py` that is causing the problem.

```py
valid_extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif']
images = request.data.getlist('images[]') #Error here I believe
directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'static', 'images', 'products')

for image in images:
    extension = os.path.splitext(image.name)[1][1:].lower()
    file_name = "".join(choice(ascii_lowercase) for i in range(16)) + "." + extension

    if extension in valid_extensions:
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in image.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
                ProductImage.objects.create(file_name=file_name, original_name=image.name, file_length=image.size, product=product, file_path=file_path.replace(os.getcwd(), '').replace('\\', '/'))
    else:
        data = {'full_messages': ['Image file type is not supported.']}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)

data = {'full_messages': ['Product created successfully.']}
return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

For some reason when I send my post request through Postman it successfully uploads the file, but when I send the same request through HTTP (Angular 8) I get errors in the console.

It says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'` and if I change the

Below is the request when sending from http
[image: the request when sending from http]

Below is the Postman request
[image: the Postman request]

Edit (including traceback)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 65, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 141, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 75, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 91, in technical_500_response
    text = reporter.get_traceback_text()
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 340, in get_traceback_text
    c = Context(self.get_traceback_data(), autoescape=False, use_l10n=False)
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 305, in get_traceback_data
    'filtered_POST_items': list(self.filter.get_post_parameters(self.request).items()),
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 177, in get_post_parameters
    return request.POST
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 110, in _get_post
    self._load_post_and_files()
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 315, in _load_post_and_files
    self._post, self._files = self.parse_file_upload(self.META, data)
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 274, in parse_file_upload
    parser = MultiPartParser(META, post_data, self.upload_handlers, self.encoding)
  File "/Users/akwild/Desktop/project1/backend/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 72, in __init__
    raise MultiPartParserError('Invalid boundary in multipart: %s' % boundary.decode())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback, and the line that the error is thrown.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Done.

Comment: Is the `POST` request made with Angular performed with the `Content-Type` header "multipart/form-data"?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule yes it is.

`addProduct(status: number, item_type: number, name: string, description: string, price: number, stock: number, tags: string, categories: string, images: any) {
    return this.http.post<any>(PRODUCTS_API_URL + '/add/', {'name': name, 'item_type': item_type, 'status': status, 'description': description, 'price': price, 'stock': stock, 'tags[eeeeee]': tags, 'categories[dasdsa]': categories, 'images[]': images}, {
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwt'), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    });
  }`

Answer (score 0):

**You should add enctype into your header instead of Content-Type. this is working for me.**

```
 headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + user.token
      })
```